# How to serve a 500 page using Sinatra?

Tags: sinatra, rack

Since Sintra is a Rack app, I think it could use Rack way:

```
get '/' do
      result = true
      if result 
             ['200', {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}, [{result:true}.to_  json]]
         else
             binding.pry
             ['500', {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}, [{result:false}.to  _json]] 
         end    
end
```

It doesn't work, it alway return a `500` page, whether the variable is `true` or `false`

Answer (score 2):

If you actually have this literal code in your app:

```
{result:true}.to_  json # <<< whitespace that shouldn't be there
```

Then your code will have a runtime exception (probably missing method `to_` or `unknown variable or method json`), and that's why you get a 500 error every time.

Comment: This actually produces a SyntaxError in this case: `SyntaxError: (irb):2: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ']'` rather than a runtime error, so the server doesn’t even start, rather than producing `500` errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a Rack-like array as a response like this, but the first item of the array needs to be a `Fixnum`specifically, rather than just something that will result in a number when parsed with `to_i`. Sinatra [checks the type of the entry](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/1.4.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1037) to determine how to handle the response.

Your response would be valid in a “pure” Rack app, but not in Sinatra. Arguably this is a bug in Sinatra, or at least the docs which [says any valid Rack response is valid](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Return%20Values).

Sinatra tries to return the whole array as the body of the reponse (since it reponds to `each`), but then fails when trying to process the array since the contents aren’t all Strings.

To fix it simply change the status codes in your responses from Strings to Fixnums:

```ruby
[200, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}, [{result:true}.to_json]]
```